# Clean boolean http query values in PHP

Tags: php

In HTTP you can send boolean values in the form of `uri?bool1&bool2`

These show up in PHP `$_GET` in the form of `$_GET['bool1'] === '' && $_GET['bool2'] === ''`

These values are easy to read with `isset` but when using `http_build_query` to write the resulting url is `uri?bool1=&bool2=`

I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this in PHP without having to write my own http_build_query

Comment: There's no difference between `?booll1&bool2` and `?bool1=&bool2=`. And, they're not really booleans, just parameters with an empty value.

Comment: As @kenny said there is no difference between the two. Only in programming codes we have difference between NULL and empty string but there is no difference in case of URI

Comment: @Gogul, that is incorrect. A `null` won't be output at all from `http_build_query`. As for there being no *practical* difference - I'm aware of that. It just seems so much uglier.

Comment: `str_replace('=&', '&', http_build_query())`

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that would work. No weird `urlencode` edge cases?

Comment: @AbraCadaver that will still leave the final trailing =, if any.  Could get rid of that with trim (easy) or regex (overkill).

Comment: AbraCadaver and user3137702 combined are perfect - I'll tick you if you answer :)

Comment: @J V I don't mean to say http_build_query will output `null`. I was also trying to convey that both `bool1&bool2` and `?bool1=&bool2=` are same

Comment: You're using tools (http_build_query and php's request parser) that are meant for x-www-form-urlencoded data, but your query string is not of that type. Will your query strings only contain `name1&name2&name3` or do you plan on having `name=value` parts as well?

Comment: That's the plan. I consider this answered but I'm waiting for user3.. or AbraCadaver to answer

Comment: err, what's the plan? a) only `name1&name2&name3` or b) can also contain `name=value` pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example would likely always be considered `boolean = false`.

The value of the parameter not the existence of a parameter determines whether it is boolean. So `bool1&bool2` is the same as `bool1=&bool2=`, which is effectively saying that both values are false, as an empty value is evaluated as false in PHP.

It would probably be better to always pass a parameter and value instead of assuming that the absence of a parameter is equivalent to false. For instance, I would send `bool1=1&bool2=0` and treat 1 as true and 0 as false. This is also how PHP will interpret these values by default.

If you don't want to always send a parameter, when its boolean value is false then another method would be to change how you retrieve the value. This is typically done with an if statement and built-in functionality for many frameworks. For instance:

```
if(isset($_GET['bool1'])){$bool1=$_GET['bool1']}else{$bool1=0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP protocol does not have types. When passing data via `GET`/`POST`/`COOKIE`, all the parameters are strings that parsed by the receiving language, in your case this is PHP.

PHP only handles `GET`/`POST`/`COOKIE` as strings and arrays, there are no `bool`, `int`, `float` or any other type, just `string` and `array` of `string`.

When you pass an empty value to a `GET` param, with or without the `=`, the value will be that of an empty string.

The values you're looking at are [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: I know, the question is how to *write* it in a "Clean" way (Without empty strings) *Edit:* And I know what urlencoding is

Comment: If you want to check the existence of a parameter in GET, you can use `isset($_GET['bool1'])` or `array_key_exists('bool1', $_GET)`. Both do the same thing however.

Comment: You've listed the only two possible ways to do something I never asked how to do. If you're not going to read the question I *do* expect you not to help me - at least it would keep SO a bit cleaner. *Nice ninja edit*

Comment: Not once does a question mark appear in your "question". So feel free to tell me: what is the question? You made an incorrect assertion on the very first line of your "question".